# Disable float for mdInput text field

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

In an Angular 4 (Material) app, I have a text field for search. When I type in the field, a second field appears showing the entered text. This new field floats as I scroll the page. How do I disable the floating behavior?

It doesn't seem to be default behavior for a text field. I've tried `md-no-float`, but that's for the placeholder text I understand. Someone suggested setting an empty `value`, so I added that, but the problem remains.

```
<md-input-container md-no-float style="width: 100%">
      <input mdInput formControlName="search" value="" placeholder="Search Terms" />
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: @Vega I'm not sure I follow. There isn't any interpolation right there. The search input is actually displayed/enabled by a radio button and the next closest tag is the results in an ngFor div.

Comment: You may mean the placeholder? https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#placeholder

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr for the problem ?

Comment: I used your code and tried to simulate what you said but it looks fine. Are you talking about  "Search terms" literal floating above the input field after you have entered something ?

Comment: @AakashUniyal, no it's the text I enter into the field--not the placeholder text. I'm just as confused. It's not standard behavior, so I'm trying to figure out what's causing it.

Comment: Yes thats strange , can you please provide your "search" formControl ?

Comment: Here's the form code... this.form = this._formBuild.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      search: '',
    })

Comment: I coded what you mentioned but unfortunately i am not able to simulate the problem . If possible provide a plunkr of your code then it would be far easier to diagnose .

Comment: @AakashUniyal OK, I'm an idiot. it's the Chrome autofill box popping up...

Comment: haha .. alright , Glad you diagnosed it :D

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It turns out it's the Chrome autocomplete popping up.

If you add `autocomplete="off"` to both the form and the input field, it will go away.

Answer (score 23):

As per version 6.4.5 of @angular/material2 you can control floating labels using `floatLabel` input property as you can see in their [floating label documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#floating-label).

```html
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'">
```

Comment: Slightly less contrived would be `floatLabel="never"`

Answer (score 14):

```html
<md-input-container [floatPlaceholder]="'never'">
```

this helped me to hide the floating placeholder

*Edit:* Since Angular Material 6

```html
<mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="never">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove placeholder attribute

```
<input matInput placeholder="Input">
```

to

```
<input matInput >
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the most recent documentation https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#floating-label, it is now `hideRequiredMarker`

```
<input matInput hideRequiredMarker placeholder="Email" required>
```